# Emojis in domain names - strange behaviour in iOS chrome

Tags: ios, unicode, dns, google-chrome-app, emoji

I was fooling around on my phone and decided to try putting an emoji in the url bar of google chrome. I entered in .com, the emoji which is equivalent to unicode `U+1F600`. Chrome ended up evaluating that as `http://xn--e28h.com/`, which took me to a "webpage unavailable" screen (`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`). I looked up `xn--e28h` on godaddy and it was unavailable.

Here are my questions:

1. Why did  turn into xn--e28h? I don't see any relation with the unicode.
2. Why are domains of this format unavailable on godaddy?
3. Bonus question: why can't we put emojis in domain names?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: rolled back edit as this didn't occur in safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. DNS uses a special way to encode Unicode into ASCII. The `xn--` prefix says that it's an encoded name, and since the whole name in this case is one Unicode codepoint the rest just looks incomprehensible. You can start reading more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).
2. Most (if not all) top-level domains have rules on which Unicode characters they allow for names in that TLD. For example, `.SE` only allows those characters that are used in one of the official languages of Sweden. This is entirely a policy thing, so the "why" gets fuzzy.
3. See 2.

Comment: On points 2/3, it's also the case that browsers won't render them correctly so as to mitigate [homograph attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack)